# I am trying to add Urdu font but it not working

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, urdu

I am downloaded Urdu font `Jameel Noori Nastaleeq` and apply to my Urdu paragraph but that font is not working.

I am trying like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Font test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    @font-face {
                 font-family: 'Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq';   font-weight: 400;
                 src:local('Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq'),
                 url('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/fonts/Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq.ttf') format('ttf'), 
               }
               .urdu{
                          font-family: 'Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq'; 
                          font-size: 30px;
                    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p style="padding-top: 150px;" class="urdu">
  پرنٹنگ اور ٹائپسیٹنگ انڈسٹری کا صرف ڈمی متن ہے۔ لورم ایپسم 1500s کے بعد سے ہی انڈسٹری کا معیاری ڈمی متن رہا ہے ، جب ایک نامعلوم پرنٹر ٹائپ کی ایک گیلی لے کر اس کو ٹائپ کرتے ہوئے ٹائپ نمونہ کی کتاب بناتا ہے۔
  </p>
  <br>
  <br>
 <p>
  پرنٹنگ اور ٹائپسیٹنگ انڈسٹری کا صرف ڈمی متن ہے۔ لورم ایپسم 1500s کے بعد سے ہی انڈسٹری کا معیاری ڈمی متن رہا ہے ، جب ایک نامعلوم پرنٹر ٹائپ کی ایک گیلی لے کر اس کو ٹائپ کرتے ہوئے ٹائپ نمونہ کی کتاب بناتا ہے۔
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.
Please help me for this.

Comment: please define "not working" - what url is being requested for the font file, does that url exist if you request it yourself directly?

Comment: @ForamTrada in my first paragraph I apply `class="urdu"` in this class I give new urdu font but in my second paragraph there is no class apply but both are shows the same font style

Comment: @farhantechno it works for me. Both paragraphs have different font size. Check the <p> by inspecting the elements of the browser.